# asp.net core IHtmlLocalizer not work

Tags: c#

I write @inject IHtmlLocalizer Localizer in _Layout.cshtml, but it isResourceNotFound = true? why?
[image: Resources]

[image: eIHtmlLocalizer Localizer]

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the Resources folder might not follow the structure of the Views folder. By convention, _Layout.cshtml is located in the Views/Shared folder. Therefore, your Resources folder should reflect that: resource files for the layout should be in Resources/Views/Shared folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is same result, I use @inject IHtmlLocalizer<Localization2.Resources.Views.Shared.Layout> Localizer  not ViewLocalizer. and I watch the Localizer,its resourceBaseName is Localization2.Resources.Resources.Views.Shared.Layout